# Are there any public services which allow broadcasting tx (like etherscan.io/pushTx)?

Tags: raw-transaction, external-api

I'm looking for a way how to broadcast signed raw tx without Ethereum node. It's possible to do via https://etherscan.io/pushTx, but I'd like to find other options because of reliability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can broadcast a transaction via any public node. [Infura](https://infura.io/) is by far the most popular.